# Can Final Cut Pro and Adobe CS4 be used on more then 1 Mac?

Tags: mac, license-key, adobe-cs4

My friend purchased FCP and CS4, and would like to let me use it. We have been told that using the license key on 2 computers is allowed...is that true and can you do more than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The license for CS4 does permit installation on **two** computers (one desktop, one portable/home computer) but only **for the same license holder** per the [EULA](http://www.adobe.com/products/eulas/pdfs/Gen_WWCombined-combined-20080623_1026.pdf). Additionally CS4 will only allow you to activate the applications on two computers at a time.

Final Cut can only legally be licensed for one desktop and one laptop per serial number (volume serial numbers excluded) for **the license holder** per the [EULA](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/finalcutstudio2.pdf) but not run at the same time.

Since you are not the license holder you are not permitted to install or use any of the programs listed. Nor is the license holder permitted to let you use them. However it is possible to use CS4 and Final Cut on more than one Mac - but be sure you're on the right side of licensing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would they know if you did run the program on more than 2 computers? 

Thanks for the answer, I will let my friend know!

Comment: @Kato: Adobe uses activation, while Final Cut checks to see it is the only serial number on the network at startup.

Comment: What does activation do?

Comment: Product activation is a license validation procedure required by some proprietary computer software programs. Without activation the product will not work. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_activation

Answer (score 0):

If these are both standard off the shelf products, you can install them as many times as you like on as many computers as you like and let as many people use them as you like **as long as it is not installed on more than one machine at any single point in time**